# Running docker-machines with machinery on bare metal

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I have four bare metal machines in which Debian9 is installed.
The root user on a Debian desktop has SSH key access to the above 4 machines as root

[Documentation](https://github.com/efrecon/machinery) gives the example of how to setup the docker machines locally using VirtualBox driver

```
db:
      driver: virtualbox
      size: 40G
      labels:
        role: db
```

How do I use machinery to install and manage docker-machines on these 4 remote bare-metal Debian installations?
I tried specifying the "generic" driver but got this error

"Driver "generic" not found. Do you have the plugin binary "docker-machine-driver-genric" accessible in your PATH?"

How to install "docker-machine-driver-genric"

Thanks :-)

--Siju

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a [newer version of docker-machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases).

The `generic` driver was built-in I thought, and wouldn't need downloaded on it's own.